# Function to find sum of digits in the number a^b where a, b are positive integers

Tags: c, algorithm, project-euler

I was solving Project Euler problem 16, which asks to find the sum of digits of the number 2 raised to the power 1000. Using Python, it can be solved in one line of code:

```
sum(map(int, list(str(2**1000))))
```

It felt too easy so I decided to write a function in C to do the same job. Here's my program. In what ways can I improve it?  Please suggest good practices also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

int sumdigit(int a, int b);

int main(void) {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 10000;
    printf("%d\n", sumdigit(a, b));
    return 0;
}

int sumdigit(int a, int b) {
    // numlen = number of digit in a^b
    // pcount = power of 'a' after ith iteration
    // dcount = number of digit in a^(pcount)

    int numlen = (int) (b * log10(a)) + 1;
    char *arr = calloc(numlen, sizeof *arr);
    int pcount = 0;
    int dcount = 1;
    arr[numlen - 1] = 1;
    int i, sum, carry;

    while(pcount < b) {
        pcount += 1;

        sum = 0; 
        carry = 0;

        for(i = numlen - 1; i >= numlen - dcount; --i) {
            sum = arr[i] * a + carry;
            carry = sum / 10;
            arr[i] = sum % 10;
        }

        while(carry > 0) {
            dcount += 1;
            sum = arr[numlen - dcount] + carry;
            carry = sum / 10;
            arr[numlen - dcount] = sum % 10;
        } 
    }

    int result = 0;
    for(i = numlen - dcount; i < numlen; ++i)
        result += arr[i];

    free(arr);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem calls for computing the sum of digits in 2<sup>1000</sup>.  You did 2<sup>10000</sup>.  Overachiever!

There are a few things you could do to improve readability.

`char *arr` looks a lot like a string.  One might initially think that you are storing the number as a string (i.e., ASCII `'0'`… `'9'`).  You could dispel that impression by changing it to `unsigned char *arr`.  To be even clearer, I would use a `typedef unsigned char digit;` so that you can declare `digit *arr`.  Then it is clear that you are using binary-coded decimal.

As long as you are doing binary-coded decimal, there is no advantage to putting the most-significant digit first.  With the least-significant digit first, the code is simpler, and there is the nice property that the number is `sum(arr[i] * 10**i for i in range(len(arr)))`.

For further readability, I would define a `struct` to represent the big decimal:

```
typedef unsigned char digit;

typedef struct {
    int capacity;
    int dcount;
    digit *digits;  /* Unsigned binary-coded decimal. The number is
                       sum(arr[i] * 10**i for i in range(dcount)) */
} bigdecimal;
```

There are a lot of variables in your `sumdigit()` — not quite a mess, but enough to start being concerned.  The function name `sumdigit` is also a bad code smell.  I would also decompose the operations for readability.  (Defining the `bigdecimal` type makes that practical.)

```
void mult(unsigned int a, bigdecimal *b) {
    int carry = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < b->dcount; ++i) {
        int sum = a * b->digits[i] + carry;
        carry = sum / 10;
        b->digits[i] = sum % 10;
    }

    while (carry > 0) {
        int sum = b->digits[b->dcount] + carry;
        carry = sum / 10;
        b->digits[b->dcount] = sum % 10;
        b->dcount++;
    }
}

bigdecimal *exponentiate(unsigned int base, unsigned int power) {
    bigdecimal *result = malloc(sizeof(bigdecimal));
    result->capacity = 1 + (int) (power * log10(base));
    result->digits = calloc(result->capacity, sizeof(digit));

    /* base**0 == 1 */
    result->digits[0] = 1;
    result->dcount = 1;

    for (int p = 0; p < power; p++) {
        mult(base, result);
    }

    return result;
}

unsigned int sumdigit(bigdecimal *b) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (int i = b->dcount - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        sum += b->digits[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

void free_bigdecimal(bigdecimal *b) {
    free(b->digits);
    free(b);
}

int main(void) {
    bigdecimal *n = exponentiate(2, 1000);
    printf("%u\n", sumdigit(n));
    free_bigdecimal(n);
    return 0;
}
```

I've used C99 variable scoping in the for-loops because it's nicer.

Comment: Compiling with optimization enabled should cause the function calls to be inlined.  (`clang` does it at `-O2`.)

Comment: In the function `sumdigit`, wouldn't iterating the `for` loop from `i = 0` to `i = b->dcount - 1` be simpler? Thanks a lot for many ideas on how to form abstractions and write clean, readable code :)

Comment: A for-loop counting up is more conventional. A for-loop counting down to 0 is a micro-optimization: CPUs have special instructions for comparing numbers with 0. The difference in performance would be negligible, so either way would be fine.

Comment: +1.   I'd be inclined to save one allocation by passing the `bigdecimal` pointer into `exponentiate` so that the caller can define it on the stack.  Either that or make the `digits` pointer a zero dimension array and allocate the struct in a single `calloc`. Also `sumdigit` should have a `const` parameter.

Comment: @WilliamMorris Learned [something new](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16553542/1157100). Thanks!